# Cosets and Kernels

Tags: group-theory

In my textbook, it says that if  $f(g_1) = f(g_2)$ where f is a homomorphism between groups, then:

$$f(g_1g_2^{-1}) = f(g_1)f(g_2^{-1}) = f(g_1)f(g_2)^{-1} = f(g_1)f(g_1)^{-1} = e, $$
$e$ being the identity element.

Therefore $g_1g_2^{-1} $belongs to $Ker(f)$ and $g_1$ and $g_2$ lie in the same coset of $Ker(f)$.

I understand everything except the conclusion that $g_1$ and $g_2$ lie in the same coset of $Ker(f)$ and was hoping that someone could explain it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. For two cosets $aH$ and $bH$, $aH=bH$ if and only if $b^{-1}a\in H$. Here take $a=g_1$ and $b=g_2$. You have shown that $g_1g_2^{-1}\in \ker(f)$. Similarly show that $g_2^{-1}g_1\in\ker(f)$. So you have $g_1\ker(f)=g_2\ker(f)$. So, $g_1=g_1e\in g_1\ker(f)=g_2\ker(f)$. Similarly $g_2\in g_2\ker(f)$. So they lie in the same coset.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a group, let $x \in G$, and let $H$ be any subgroup of $G$. Then the left coset of $H$ in $G$ determined by $x$ is given by
$$xH \colon= \left\{ \ xh \colon \ h \in H \ \right\},$$ 
and the right coset of $H$ in $G$ determined by $x$ is given by 
$$Hx \colon= \left\{ \ hx \colon \ h \in H \ \right\}.$$ 
Thus, $y \in xH$ if and only if $y = xh$ for some element $h \in H$, and so $x^{-1}y \in H$.

Similarly, $z \in Hx$ if and only if $z = hx$ for some $h \in H$, and so $zx^{-1} \in H$.

Finally, if $H$ is a normal subgroup, then $x H = H x$.

And, $\mathrm{ker} f$ is indeed a normal subgroup.

Hope you can now figure out the answer to your question.